# Background Images not fully loading in FIrefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

http://www.sunmetrix.com

The above URL is working fine in Chrome, IE and Safari but in firefox.

There was a warning "using deprecated" in Firefox earlier which I fixed using the latest version of JQuery in my file but I am still stuck up this issue.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It's working fine without any errors or warnings in the console for me. Using Firefox 35.0.1 on Linux.

Comment: Try it on Windows if you can